# Не забанят ли мой дискорд аккаунт, если я напишу простецкого бота?

Tags: javascript

Когда-то я пробовал автоматизировать рабочий процесс в дискорде при помощи автокликера мышью, после чего я словил бан на свой аккаунт дискорд. Сейчас я размышляю над скриптом, который просто будет определенным образом ставить реакции/писать "+" в чат в зависимости от роли человека, отправившего сообщение выше.
Все это будет реализовано через расширение "Custom JavaScript for Websites 2" (дискорд в браузере).
Вопрос знатокам: не забанят ли меня на этот раз за такие махинации? Есть ли вариант лучше и безопаснее?

Comment: *в отличии от прошлого раза, сейчас я планирую встраивать код непосредственно в сайт Discord'а 
**админ доступа к каналу у меня нет, по этому классического бота на питоне написать не вариант

Comment: Почему бы вам просто не создать бота?

Comment: у меня нет админки чтобы добавлять ботов на сервер